# Gnome shell does not work?

Tags: 11.10, gnome

I installed gnome shell but when I start it it's the design of gnome classic...
what can I do? I already reinstalled it. I have Ubuntu 11.10.

Comment: It is defaulting to fall-back session. What graphics card do you have?

Comment: ASUS HD 6670 I installed the drivers

Answer (score 0):

This might be trivial

To make sure, install again gnome-shell from a terminal:

> sudo apt-get install gnome-shell

Log out your session or restart your computer.
Now, select the Gnome-shell session at the login screen. Otherwise it will start your default session, which in this case might be classic Gnome. Check this image for reference.

[image]

Comment: I selected GNOME and not GNOME Classic. GNOME-shell doesn't exist.

Comment: then you don't have it installed I am afraid. Try this in a terminal: sudo apt-get install gnome-shell, then log out or restart and check if it is there

Comment: Output in terminal:
gnome-shell is already the newest version.
The same when I log out or restart.

Comment: Ok, try running this in a terminal: gnome-shell --replace (and post output here please).

Comment: (gnome-shell:3566): Gdk-WARNING **: The program 'gnome-shell' received an X Window System error.
This probably reflects a bug in the program.
The error was 'BadRequest (invalid request code or no such operation)'.
  (Details: serial 147 error_code 1 request_code 136 minor_code 19)
  (Note to programmers: normally, X errors are reported asynchronously;
   that is, you will receive the error a while after causing it.

Comment: To debug your program, run it with the --sync command line
   option to change this behavior. You can then get a meaningful
   backtrace from your debugger if you break on the gdk_x_error() function.)